# Recover Windows 7 Network Setting from old Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, import

I had my computer stop working and am using a different one now. I'd like to pull off my old network settings for one of the two Ethernet ports as I need to know the settings. I have full access to the old drive as an external. I can't remember how I set up the IP settings, but I cannot get the same setup to work now, so I figured I could narrow it down if I knew the static IP or at least if it used DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you had some kind of static configuration that you have forgotten, as opposed to the ports simply being DHCP.

You need to open up regit, and Load Hive from the old hdd.

The hive you need to load is the old HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, it is located, on the old hdd, under \Windows\System32\Config. It is called 'system' (no extension)

You will want to browse to ControlSet001\services. Under this branch, you will see a bunch of english looking names, these are your old computers services. What you are interested in is the ones with mumbo jumbo GUID names, i.e {14894580-083E-48DD-B787-3F8C39F84133}

You will see a few of them. Just look inside every single one, they should contain two folders, Parameters and Tcpip, until you find the info you are looking for.

Edit: A better location to find this informtion is under services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces! Also, under Services\TcpIp\Parameters you will find information such as Hostname

Comment: That worked great, but is there a way to find the name of the network adapter, the gateway, and any DNS servers?

Comment: Possibly under Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Comment: I didn't need to look there, because I found the real source of my problem. Thanks for the help!